# Question about notation of sequences and equivalence classes.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, equivalence-relations

In [these notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M55a.02/pdflatex/top6.pdf) (see pg3 second-to-last paragraph), what does $d(x_k,x^\ast_{N_k})$ mean? The term $x_k$ lies in $X$, but $x^\ast_{N_k}$ is a class of Cauchy sequences in $X$. Should I take $d(x_k,x_{N_k}^\ast)$ to mean the distance function on $X^\ast$ and identify $x_k$ with the constant Cauchy sequence whose terms are all $x_k$? If so, I can see how one deduces that $\{x_k\}$ is at distance zero from $\{x_n^\ast\}$, but I don't see how to show that $\{x_k\}$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Since $X$ is isometrically embedded in $X^*$, you can think of $x_k$ as the equivalence class of the constant sequence $(x,x,x,\dots)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you’re to identify $x_k$ with the equivalence class of the constant sequence $\langle x_k,x_k,x_k,\ldots\rangle$ and take the distance in $X^*$. Given $k\in\Bbb Z^+$, there is an $m_k\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(x_\ell^*,x_n^*)<\frac1k$ whenever $\ell,n\ge m_k$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $m_k\ge k$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ and that the sequence $\langle m_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is increasing. But then for $\ell,n\ge m_k$ we must have

$$d(x_\ell,x_n)\le d(x_\ell,x_{m_\ell}^*)+d(x_{m_\ell}^*,x_{m_n}^*)+d(x_{m_n}^*,x_n)<\frac1\ell+\frac1k+\frac1n\le\frac3k\;,$$

and $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$.

Comment: what is $m_\epsilon$?

Comment: @wellynaught: A typo that I’ll fix in a moment.

Comment: why does the $<$ follow after "we must have"? In the notes it's set up so that $d(x_k,x^\ast_{m_k})<1/2k$. Why does it also follow that $d(x_j,x^\ast_{m_k})<1/2k$ for $j \geq m_k$? Shouldn't it only be the case for $j=k$?

Comment: @wellynaught: Sorry: my mind ran ahead of my fingers when I was revising an earlier version. I’ve fixed it now.

Comment: Hm. How do you get $d(x^\ast_{m_\ell},x^\ast_{m_n}) < 1/k$? I don't see how $m_\ell,m_k\geq m_k$ to get the $<1/k$. I see how the rest works.

Comment: @wellynaught: Argh. I inadvertently omitted omitted an important sentence, which has now been restored. Once you have an $m_n$ that works, any bigger integer works too, so you can assume that $m_n\ge n$ and that the sequence of $m_n$s is increasing. Thus, in the actual argument $m_\ell\ge\ell\ge m_k$ and $m_n\ge n\ge m_k$.